# What starts the reaction in a voltaic cell?

Tags: electrochemistry

[image]

In a zinc-copper voltaic cell,
What causes the initial electron movement from the zinc to the copper?

I understand that copper would pull the electrons more strongly than zinc, but only if it is electron deficient. Both half cells of the voltaic cell are electrically neutral (same amount of electrons and protons), so I don't understand what would cause the electron transfer / oxidation.

Also, I understand that $\ce{CuSO4}$ solution in the cathode half cell is needed so that the $\ce{Cu++}$ will accept the electrons, but what's the function of the $\ce{ZnSO4}$ in the anode half cell?

Comment: *The fact that the chemical potential of the two separate half is not the same*. I don't claim it is simple. But you can ask the same for every reaction not only for redox ones in an electrochemical apparatus.

Answer (score 1):

For both electrodes, regardless of their galvanic connection, are ongoing the opposite processes

$$\ce{M(s) <=> M^n+(aq) + n e-}$$.

The forward process charges the electrode negatively, but slows down at more negative potentials.

The backward process charges the electrode positively, but slows down at more positive potentials.

As the resulting net effect, an electrode establishes such an equilibrium potential, where both processes have the equal rate and the zero net effect.
These equilibrium potentials are different for different combinations of electrode material and solution composition.

---

When you connect 2 electrodes ( connected also internally by a free ion passage ) by a galvanic circuit, different electrostatic potentials lead to the electric current. The current disbalances the equilibrium state on electrodes and one of the respective processes takes the upper hand.

> That's the core of my question. Where is the difference in the electrostatic potential? If we count the electrons and protons in each half cell, they're the same, so what would still cause the electrons to move?

They are not exactly same and there are differences within the half cells, between electrodes and electrolyte.

> We started with neutral electrodes and neutral electrolyte, where did the difference in potential came from? I'm sorry if I wasn't clear in the original question, but that is exactly what's confusing me. If I'm able to see how the electrostatic potential is created, all the other pieces will fall into place for me.

Dissolving a metal electrode charges it negatively and solution positively. The opposite process - metal depositioning - does the opposite. The metal with the greater tendency to dissolve causes the electrolyte to be more positive than the one in the other cell, cause positive ions ions to migrate there and negative here. As result, the net charge of half cells is not zero anymore and neither the charge of the electrodes.

---

The "spectator" ions like $\ce{SO4^2-}$ do not take part in electrode reactions. They electromigrate according to the local solution electrostatic potential gradient away from the $\ce{Cu}$ side, where they are becoming excessive and forming slightly negative solution charge. They pass the salt bridge ( or a porous membrane or a diaphragm) to the $\ce{Zn}$ side, where they are needed to counterpart being created $\ce{Zn^2+(aq)}$ to cancel slighly positive solution charge there.

Comment: `When you connect 2 electrodes by a galvanic circuit, different electrostatic potentials lead to the electric current.` - That's the core of my question. Where is the difference in the electrostatic potential? If we count the electrons and protons in each half cell, they're the same, so what would still cause the electrons to move?

Comment: We started with neutral electrodes and neutral electrolyte, where did the difference in potential came from? I'm sorry if I wasn't clear in the original question, but that is exactly what's confusing me. If I'm able to see how the electrostatic potential is created, all the other pieces will fall into place for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think your iterpretation of electrochemical cell is incorrect.

Firstly, the electrode is not dipped
in a neutral electrolyte. You must have seen that whenever an electrolyte is represented for an electrochemical cell, it always has "(aq)" attached to it. This means that the electrolyte, say ZnSO4 is not as a neutrally bonded compound (as i think you are interpreting the electrolyte), in fact, it is in form of its ions Zn²+ and SO4²-. This is the key to the difference in charges which initiates the reaction.

Consider an electrochemical cell:

Zn|ZnSO4(**aq**)||CuSO4(**aq**)|Cu

We can see that the Zn (neutral) electrode is dipped in a sea of Zn²+ and SO4²– ions. Sometimes, the SO4²– ions attract the Zn in the neutral electrode (Note that at molecular level, "sometimes" can even mean a million times because there are just so many atoms/particles/species) which falls into the electrolyte as Zn²+ towards that attracting SO4²- ion. Since so many Zn²+ ions leave the electrode (again, sometimes at molecular level means a lot of times), the electrode acquires a negative charge. These electrons are attracted by the cathode... Voila! the cell reaction has been initiated.

Also consider that previously there were equal amount of Zn²+ and SO4²- ions in the electrolyte so that the net charge of the electrolyte is zero. But since "some" SO4²- ions attracted more Zn²+ ions from the electrode, the electrolyte becomes positively charged. To satisfy the positive charge (so that electrolyte becomes neutral again) an equal amount of (an amount equal to the amount of extra Zn²+ in the electrolyte) negatively charged ions are dropped from the Salt Bridge to the electrolyte (Say if the salt bridge is KCl, then Cl- ions will be dropped).

**What keeps the cell reaction going once it has been initiated?**

Notice that there are less number of Zn atoms in the electrode as some have been pulled into the electrolyte by SO4²- until there are so much extra Zn²+ ions in the electrolyte that SO4²- hardly pulls any more atoms from the electrode. This should stop the cell reaction. But the twist comes with the arrival of even more negatively charged ions (Cl- ions from the salt bridge). These extra negative ions can pull even more Zn²+ from the neutral Zn electrode.
Once again the electrons remaining in the anode due to loss of these Zn atoms flow to the cathode and even more Cl- ions are dropped into the electrolyte to again neutralise the electrolyte and the reaction goes on.

**Why do we use the "(aq)" notation after the electrolyte to represent that it is in ionic form instead of just writing it as ions? (like
Zn|Zn²+SO4²-||Cu²+SO4²-|Cu)**

Well in some cases the electrolyte is written just as ions but there are two good enough points (i think) as to why the (aq) is used to denote the ionisation of electrolytes.

First off, "aq" generally implies that the substance is dissolved in water. Whenever an ionic compound (electrolytes considered in cell reactions are ionic) is dissolved in water, it dissociates into separate ions. This property is so common infact that in electrochemistry, "aq" denotes ionisation more than it denotes solution in water.

The second point though is based on my opinion. In science we generally try to shorten our representations and since, in an aqueous solution, most ionic compounds dissociate into ions, and since electrolytes are ionic and need to be in ionic form for the cell reaction to happen, why not just use "aq" to denote the ionisation of electrolyte as as well!

Hope this answers your question! :D

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer a "human-like" picture. You may prefer to interpret the chemistry of the cell in saying that the zinc atom "feels like" losing its electrons to become a zinc cation. On the other side, the copper electrode has not at all the same tendency. It is even ready to accept foreign electrons to discharge its own cations. I know this explanation is not very scientific, and I beg your pardon for stating it. From my experience in teaching chemistry to unmotivated high school students, I know it helps.

Now the function of the $\ce{ZnSO4}$ in the anodic solution is to help electrically speaking, because pure water is an insulator. If the anodic compartment were just pure water, the first $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ ions created in the water from zinc metal would prevent the next ones from appearing in solution, and the cell would soon stop working. But if there are already some $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ in the solution, the newly created $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ ions would simply push the already dissolved cations through the solution up to the bridge where the sulfate ions are coming from the cathodic region.

Comment: `the zinc atom "feels like" losing its electrons to become a zinc cation` - but why that happens? If we count the electrons and protons, they're the same amount. Is it caused by something that doesn't boil down to electrostatic energy? If it is, then what is it?

Comment: @Toi Yiot This happens because redox potential is negative